# Could not find com.androidx.support:support-v4:28.0.0. // Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

So I am running the Android Application but it stops in middle of Gradle Build and Displays the Error as:-

```
Could not find com.androidx.support:support-v4:28.0.0. Required by:
project :app  
Search in build.gradle files
```

My Gradle File is as Follows:-

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.alliaiseV1"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.androidx.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:20.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.databinding:viewbinding:7.1.2'


//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.0.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.0'

//lifecycle
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1")

//coroutines
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.0")
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.0")

//Fragment Navigation
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.1'
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0-alpha03")
implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0-alpha03")

//Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

//CardView
implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")
//splashscreen API
implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta02"

//blur
implementation 'io.alterac.blurkit:blurkit:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.MikeOrtiz:TouchImageView:1.4.1'

//paging
implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.1")

//touch
implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0'
}
```

After that error I tried to remove the Dependency :

```
implementation 'com.androidx.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Than after that I tried Running that got the error:-

```
    Execution failed for task ':App : merge Debug Resources'.
> A failure occurred while executing 
Com. android. build. Gradle. internal. res. Resource Compiler Runnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.
```

Please help me regarding how do I solve this issue in Gradle to make the application work.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue got resolved,  the problem was in one of the string.xml files where there was a ' used in between of string
However this error acctuly means is there is some error in your resource files you need to start from drawbles and read every line trying to find error in your resource file.